# Register PPAPI plugin to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ppapi

I am developing an out-of-process plugin for Chrome, where I need some kind of resource management mechanism (shared memory) that can be used by multiple processes. Then I found the Pepper plugin and it looks promising to achieve my goal.

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/ppapi/source/browse/trunk/examples/stub/stub.cc) provided in ppapi example folder is a simple stub plugin. According to [another document](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/pepper-plugin-implementation) I could load it by the following command:

```
chrome.exe --ppapi-out-of-process --register-pepper-plugins="[chromium_path]\src\build\Debug\ppapi_example_cc_stub.dll;application/x-ppapi-example-stub"
```

The problem is that I did not find a clean way to load it without specify the dll path and the MIME type, thus the plugin can be simply loaded by starting the Chrome executable.

I guess I need to add new items to Windows Registry or define a manifest.json file, but I do not know how to. Can some one give me an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encounted the same problem when developing my PPAPI plugin. But open the chrome://plugins,  there are 3 PPAPI plguins. others are NPAPI plugin. I modify the file name of PPAPI plugins dll (pdf.dll). restart the chrome. I found that the chrome internel pdf plugin  not work.

I belive that the registration information of PPAPI plugin is fixed in the executable binary file of chrome browser. Search the  sources of chromium, I found [this](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/common/chrome_paths.cc&exact_package=chromium&q=libpdf.so&ct=rc&cd=1&sq=).

```
// File name of the internal PDF plugin on different platforms.
const FilePath::CharType kInternalPDFPluginFileName[] =
#if defined(OS_WIN)
    FILE_PATH_LITERAL("pdf.dll");
#elif defined(OS_MACOSX)
    FILE_PATH_LITERAL("PDF.plugin");
#else  // Linux and Chrome OS
    FILE_PATH_LITERAL("libpdf.so");
#endif
```

So maybe the npapi is more practical.